# Credit Card (saved) payment method in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am quiet new in magento and would like to ask about the payment option credit card (saved) 
I didn’t found any tutorials or opinion how it works 
Okay a customer is buying a product choosing credit card (saved) as payment and what is happening then?

I have the details about the card- but how to finished the transaction? 
What do I have to do with it- as shop owner?

Have no idea !!

Answer (score 0):

credit card (saved) payment method is given just for development phase.

It is not meant for live websites, because it makes payment even when you try to order with Test Credit Card Account Numbers.